# How to Change date-picker design in magento front-end?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

How can i change date-picker design in magento?

By default Magento gives date-picker

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can easily style your datepicker with CSS. You can find CSS files in directory skin/frontend/[package]/[theme]/css.